# How many combinations of 5 balls from 16 balls can you have in which the numbers on the balls are distinct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, discrete-optimization

We have $8$ blue balls that are numbered $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. We have $8$ red balls that are numbered $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.

I think it should be ${8 \choose 5}\cdot 2^5$.

There ${8 \choose 5}$ is as choosing $5$ distinct digits from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$
and $2^5$ is as choosing the color either blue or red for the balls we chose.

Is my thinking correct? Any suggestions or corrections?

Comment: Your logic seems to be correct to me.

Comment: $\checkmark$ Yes.  Select 5 of 8 distinct digits and then assign 1 of 2 colours to each: $\dbinom 8 5\cdot 2^5$.